# Run .NET Framework on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, .net, raspberry-pi, arm

In short, I have a console x64(/x86) C# project that is using .NET Framework 4.7.1. I need to run this project on a Raspberry Pi, some way, somehow.

I tried Mono on Raspbian. Mono worked for some of the project, but failed for two of its key libraries.

Next I tried Windows IOT. This worked well for the most part, but I couldn't run my project. After publishing it and uploading it to the Pi, it says the project is not compatible with the version of Windows I'm running. I think this might only be for .NET Core projects?

Next I tried emulating x86 through Wine on Ubuntu which was just a nightmare.

Finally I tried installing Windows Desktop on the Pi, but it lacks network adapters, and my project needs the internet to function.

What are my other options? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a lot of problems, i have a C# application that needs to be run on `arm` platform. The solution I found was to make an application in Visual Studio 2012 (a Windows Form Application project), and run on RaspberryPi3 using `mono`:

```
mono myapplication.exe
```

In my case I use only a library of access to GPIO, and other common libraries (`xml`, `json`), so it worked fine. It would be interesting if you could quote which libraries didn't work for you.

Comment: The libraries that didn't work with Mono were [`Discord.Net`](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/tree/dev) and [`MediaWiki`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetwikibot/).

Comment: I will do some tests using these libraries and give a feedback :)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. Discord.Net fails at the log-in stage (`await DiscordClient.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, discordToken);`) and MediaWiki fails at either the log-in or when it attempts to edit a page. (`site = new Site(@"<wiki url>", username, password); Page p = await "<page name>".Load(); p.Save("new page content", "edit summary", true, true);`) Let me know if you need any help getting either library working.